# Why does Roboto Regular display as bold?

Tags: fonts

I downloaded the Roboto font from the Android website.  All the weights—including Roboto Regular—display properly in the font viewer, but when I try to set it as my title bar font (with gnome-tweak-tool) or use it in an application, Roboto Regular always displays as Roboto Bold.  As far as I can tell, this only seems to affect Roboto.

I am on Ubuntu 12.10 now (with Unity replaced with Gnome 3 if that matters).  I never checked in 12.04, but I know I did not have this problem in 11.04.

Comment: The same problem in 12.04, unity. Try to remove all except regular fonts - this worked for me.

Comment: Is it enough to remove everything from the ~/.fonts folder?

Comment: So, this is what i did and it works :)
`dst="$HOME/.fonts/roboto" && mkdir -p $dst && cp Roboto-{Bold,BoldItalic,Italic,Regular}.ttf $dst && fc-cache -f -v`

Comment: @disfated, I tried your suggestion (moving the Roboto files to a subfolder within .fonts) without much success.  I did notice, though, that your description did not list the Black, Light, Thin, or Narrow varients (or the Italic variants of each of those).  Should I copy all Roboto variants to the subfolder or only some of them?

Comment: This is what i'm trying to tell you - install only few of font variants - Bold,BoldItalic,Italic,Regular - not all.

Comment: Oh, so remove all variants except the basic ones from .fonts?  Is there any way to get them to work too?   
   
Edit: I tried installing only those four variants, and I still have the problem.  Interestingly, GIMP lists “Roboto” and “Roboto Italic” twice each, and both are bolder than “Roboto Bold” and “Roboto Bold Italic”.

Comment: Okay, so I just found copies of Roboto Black in .local/share/fonts.  I do not recall ever putting _any_ version of Roboto there, let alone just the Black variant.  That would explain the duplicate listing.  
  
Deleting it fixed Roboto Regular showing up as Roboto Black.  I added the other variants back one by one and it seems Roboto Black is the only variant that cannot coexist with the others (Bold, Light, Thin, Condensed, and the italic version of each of those work fine).  Do you know why that is?

Comment: It should be noted that on Ubuntu 14.04, the fonts are in ~/.local/share/fonts. I had this same problem. When I removed all my Roboto-* fonts from there, the bolding on the web issue went away. So now I'm wondering if I need to try this technique of using subfolder to store all the Roboto's, or just not install Roboto Black. I'll test.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tutorial I found linked to on the Arch Linux AUR page. http://nileshgr.com/2013/02/24/configuring-roboto-font-in-linux